# What are the different methods to retrieve elements in a DataFrame Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are at least 6 ways to retrieve elements in a pandas `DataFrame`: `.iloc`, `.loc`, `.iat`, `.at`, `.ix`, and using directly the `[]` operator.

What's the difference between them ? How do they handle missing labels/out of range positions ? How do they differ from `Series` look-up ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use the same methods of a `Series` (`.loc`, `.iloc`, `.ix` and the `[]` operator) and the `DataFrame`-specific ones `.iat` and `.at` to retrieve elements from a `DataFrame`, with the syntax:

```
newobj = df.method_choosen[row,column]
```

In most cases the new object will be a new `DataFrame`, in some cases a `Series` and in still other cases it will be just a scalar value.

The general rule is that `.iloc[]` and `.iat[]` select by position, `.loc[]` and `.at[]` select by label, with the first parameter being the row(s) (eventually all rows using `:`) and the second (optional) parameter is the column(s).

BUT remember:

- Differently from `.ix`, `.iloc` and `.loc` that always select rows first, `[]` selects columns when a single element or a turple is given (and it doesn't accept a second parameter). However when a slice is passed, it selects rows!
- Selecting a dataframe with the `[]` operator using a single element is always by label, not as selecting from a Series where if a integer is passed to a string-indexed Series it is interpreted as position-based lookup.
- `.at` and `.iat` accept only single column and row values, they give an error if a slice or a turple is passed.

There are some other inconsistencies that are "shared" with serie look-up:

- As for the Series, when the slice is given to a position-based look-up the last element is excluded, but when it is a label-based look up, the last element is included.
- The return value can be (a) a `DataFrame` with just the column header and no rows, (b) a `DataFrame` with the requested data displayed as `NaN` or (c) one of the exceptions `KeyError`, `IndexError`, `ValueError`, `TypeError`.

Here is the complete table with (almost) all the possibilities (working with pandas 0.17.1, NumPy 1.10.4, Python 3.4.3). See also the [equivalent question for Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600403/what-are-the-different-methods-to-retrieve-elements-in-a-pandas-series).

### Case 1: DataFrame with integer index

```
di = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,120).reshape(5,4),index=[10,11,12,13,14],columns=[20,21,22,23])
di
     20    21    22    23
10  100   101   102   103
11  104   105   106   107
12  108   109   110   111
13  112   113   114   115
14  116   117   118   119

** Single element **                                       ** Slice **                                                                             ** Tuple **
di[20]        -> COL -> LAB -> {10:100,11:104,..,14:116}  di[0:1]             -> ROWS -> POS -> {10:{20:100,..,23:103}}                          di[[20,22]]            -> COLS -> LAB -> {10:{20:100,22:102},..,14:{20:116,22:118}}
di[3]         -> COL -> LAB -> KeyError                   di[200:202]         -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                           di[[20]]               -> COLS -> LAB -> {10:{20:100},..,14:{20:116}} (df)
di[0,1]                     -> TypeError                  di[12:14]           -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                           di[[0]]                -> COLS -> LAB -> KeyError
di[10,21]                   -> TypeError                  di[:,2]             -> ROWS -> POS -> TypeError                                        di[[10,11],[20,22]]                   -> TypeError
---                                                       ---                                                                                    ---
di.ix[0]      -> ROW -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.ix[0:1]          -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                           di.ix[[20,22]]         -> ROWS -> LAB -> {20:{20:NaN,..,23:NaN},22:{20:NaN,..,23:NaN}}
di.ix[13]     -> ROW -> LAB -> {20:112,..,23:115}}        di.ix[200:202]      -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                           di.ix[[11,14]]         -> ROWS -> LAB -> {11:{20:104,..,23:107},14:{20:116,..,23:119}}
di.ix[0,1]    -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.ix[12:14]        -> ROWS -> LAB -> {12:{20:108,..,23:111},..,14:{20:116,..,23:119}} di.ix[[11]]            -> ROWS -> LAB -> {11:{20:104,..,23:107}}
di.ix[10,21]  -> R/C -> LAB -> 101                        di.ix[:,20]         -> ROW  -> LAB -> {10:100,..,14:116}                               di.ix[[0]]             -> ROWS -> LAB -> {20:{20:NaN,..,23:NaN}}
---                                                       di.ix[:,20:22]      -> R/C  -> LAB -> {10:{20:100,22:102},..,14:{20:116,..,22:118}}    di.ix[[10,11],[20,22]] -> R/C  -> LAB -> {10:{20:100,22:102},11:{20:104,22:106}}
di.iloc[0]    -> ROW -> POS -> {20:100,..,23:103}         di.ix[10:14,20:22]  -> R/C  -> LAB -> {10:{20:100,22:102},..,14:{20:116,..,22:118}}    di.ix[[16],[26]]       -> R/C  -> LAB -> {16:{26:NaN}}
di.iloc[13]   -> ROW -> POS -> IndexError                 di.ix[10,:]         -> COL  -> LAB -> {20:100,..,23:103}                               ---
di.iloc[0,1]  -> R/C -> POS -> 101                        ---                                                                                    di.iloc[[20,22]]       -> ROWS -> POS -> IndexError
---                                                       di.iloc[0:1]        -> ROWS -> POS -> {10:{20:100,..,23:103}}                          di.iloc[[11,14]]       -> ROWS -> POS -> IndexError
di.loc[0]     -> ROW -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.iloc[200:202]    -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                           di.iloc[[11]]          -> ROWS -> POS -> IndexError
di.loc[13]    -> ROW -> LAB -> {20:112,..,23:115}         di.iloc[12:14]      -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                           di.iloc[[0]]           -> ROWS -> POS -> {10:{20:100,..,23:103}}
di.loc[10,21] -> R/C -> LAB -> 101                        di.iloc[0:1,2:3]    -> R/C  -> POS -> {10:{22:102}}                                    di.iloc[[0],[1]]       -> R/C  -> POS -> {10:{21:101}}
---                                                       di.iloc[6:8,6:8]    -> R/C  -> POS -> Empty df                                         ---
di.iat[0]            -> POS -> TypeError                  ---                                                                                    di.loc[[20,22]]        -> ROWS -> LAB -> KeyError
di.iat[0,1]   -> R/C -> POS -> 101                        di.loc[0:1]         -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                           di.loc[[11,14]]        -> ROWS -> LAB -> {11:{20:104,..,23:107},14:{20:116,..,23:119}}
di.iat[0,15]  -> R/C -> POS -> IndexError                 di.loc[200:202]     -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                           di.loc[[11]]           -> ROWS -> LAB -> {11:{20:104,..,23:107}}
di.iat[15,0]  -> R/C -> POS -> IndexError                 di.loc[12:14]       -> ROWS -> LAB -> {12:{20:108,..,23:111},..,14:{20:116,..,23:119}} di.loc[[0]]            -> ROWS -> LAB -> KeyError
di.iat[15,15] -> R/C -> POS -> IndexError                 di.loc[10:11,20:21] -> R/C  -> LAB -> {10:{20:100,21:101},11:{20:104,21:105}           di.loc[[10],[21]]      -> R/C  -> POS -> {10:{21:101}}
---                                                       di.loc[16:18,26:28] -> R/C  -> LAB -> Empty df                                         ---
di.at['a']           -> LAB -> ValueError                 ---                                                                                    di.iat[[0,1],[2,3]]    -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
di.at[10,21]  -> R/C -> LAB -> 101                        di.iat[0:1,2:3]     -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError                                       di.iat[[0],[2]]        -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
di.at[0,1]    -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.iat[0:1,2]       -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError                                       ---
di.at[0,21]   -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.iat[:,2]         -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError                                       di.at[[10,11],[22,23]] -> R/C  -> LAB -> ValueError
di.at[10,0]   -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError                   di.iat[2,:]         -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError                                       
                                                          ---
                                                          di.at[10:11,22:23]  -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
                                                          di.at[0:21,22]      -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
                                                          di.at[:,22]         -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
                                                          di.at[12,:]         -> R/C  -> POS -> ValueError
```

### Case 2: DataFrame with string index

```
ds = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,120).reshape(5,4),index=[10,11,12,13,14],columns=[20,21,22,23])
ds
    A     B     C     D
a   100   101   102   103
b   104   105   106   107
c   108   109   110   111
d   112   113   114   115
e   116   117   118   119

** Single element **                                             ** Slice **                                                                                       ** Tuple **
ds[2]           -> COL -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds[0:1]                 -> ROWS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':103}}                              ds[[0,2]]              -> COLS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,'C':102},...,'e':{'A':116,'C':118}}
ds['B']         -> COL -> LAB -> {'a': 101,..,'e':117} (Series)  ds[200:202]             -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                                  ds[[0]]                -> COLS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,...,'e'{'A':116}}
ds['a','b']            -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds['a':'e']             -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':103},..,'e':{'A':116,..,'D':119}}  ds[[10]]               -> COLS -> POS -> IndexError
ds[0,1]                -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds['g':'i']             -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                                  ds[['A','C']]          -> COLS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,'C':102},...,'e':{'A':116,'C':118}}
---                                                              ds[:,'B']                       -> LAB -> TypeError                                               ds[['A']]              -> COLS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,...,'e'{'A':116}}
ds.ix[0]        -> ROW -> POS->  {'A':100,..,'D':103}            ----                                                                                              ds[['E']]              -> COLS -> LAB -> KeyError
ds.ix[20]       -> ROW -> POS->  IndexError                      ds.ix[0:1]              -> ROWS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':103}}                              ds[['a'],['B']]                -> LAB -> TypeError
ds.ix['a']      -> ROW -> LAB -> {'A':100,..,'D':103}            ds.ix[200:202]          -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                                  ---
ds.ix['f']      -> ROW -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds.ix['a':'e']          -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':103},..,'e':{'A':116,..,'D':119}}  ds.ix[[0]]             -> ROWS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':103}}
ds.ix[0,1]      -> R/C -> POS -> 101                             ds.ix['g':'i']          -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                                  ds.ix[[15]]            -> ROWS -> POS -> IndexError
ds.ix['a','B']  -> R/C -> LAB -> 101                             ds.ix[0:1,1:2]          -> R/C  -> POS -> {'a':{'B':101}}                                         ds.ix[['a','c']]       -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':111},'c':{'A':108,..,'D':111}}
ds.ix[10,10]    -> R/C -> POS->  IndexError                      ds.ix['a':'b','A':'C']  -> R/C  -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'C':102},'b':{'A':104,'C':106}}        ds.ix[['g']]           -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'g':{'A':NaN,..,'D':NaN}}  
ds.ix['g','G']  -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError                        ----                                                                                              ds.ix[[0],[1]]         -> R/C  -> POS -> {'a':{'B':101}}
---                                                              ds.iloc[0:1]            -> ROWS -> POS -> {'a':{'A':100,..'D':103}}                               ds.ix[['a'],['B']]     -> R/C  -> LAB -> {'a':{'B':101}}
ds.iloc[0]      -> ROW -> POS -> {'A':100,..,'D':103}            ds.iloc['a':'e']        -> ROWS -> POS -> ValueError                                              ----
ds.iloc['a']    -> ROW -> POS -> TypeError                       ds.iloc[15:18]          -> ROWS -> POS -> df with column headers                                  ds.iloc[[0]]           -> ROWS -> POS ->{'a':{'A':100,..,'D':111}}
ds.iloc[15]     -> ROW -> POS -> IndexError                      ds.iloc[0:1,1:2]        -> ROWS -> POS -> {'a':{'B':101}}                                         ds.iloc[[15,18]]       -> ROWS -> POS -> IndexError
ds.iloc[0,1]    -> R/C -> POS -> 101                             ----                                                                                              ds.iloc[['a','c']]     -> ROWS -> POS -> TypeError
---                                                              ds.loc[0:1]             -> ROWS -> LAB -> TypeError                                               ds.iloc[[0],[1]]       -> R/C  -> POS -> {'a':{'B':101}}
ds.loc[0]       -> ROW -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds.loc['a':'e']         -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..'D':103},..,'e':{'A':116,..,'D':119}}   ----
ds.loc['a']     -> ROW -> LAB -> {'A':100,...,'D':103}           ds.loc[g:i]             -> ROWS -> LAB -> df with column headers                                  ds.loc[[0]]            -> ROWS -> LAB -> KeyError
ds.loc['f']     -> ROW -> LAB -> KeyError                        ds.loc['a':'b','A':'C'] -> R/C  -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'C':102},'b':{'A':104,'C':106}}        ds.loc[['a','c']]      -> ROWS -> LAB -> {'a':{'A':100,..,'D':111},'c':{'A':108,..,'D':111}}
ds.loc['a','B'] -> R/C -> LAB -> 101                             ----                                                                                              ds.loc[['a'],['B']]    -> R/C  -> LAB -> {'a':{'B':101}}
---                                                              ds.iat[0:1]                     -> POS -> ValueError                                              ----
ds.iat[0]       -> POS -> TypeError                              ds.iat[0:1,2:3]                 -> POS -> ValueError                                              ds.iat[[0,3]]                 -> POS -> ValueError
ds.iat[0,1]     -> R/C -> POS -> 101                             ----                                                                                              ds.iat[[0,3],[1]]      -> R/C -> POS -> ValueError
ds.iat[0,15]    -> R/C -> POS -> IndexError                      ds.at['a':'b']                  -> LAB -> TypeError                                               ----
---                                                              ds.at['a':'b','A':'C']          -> LAB -> TypeError                                               ds.at[['a','c']]              -> LAB -> ValueError
ds.at['a'] -> LAB -> typeError                                                                                                                                     ds.at[['a','c'],['B']] -> R/C -> LAB -> TypeError
ds.at['a','B'] -> R/C -> LAB -> 101
ds.at[0,1]     -> R/C -> LAB -> ValueError
ds.at['a','G'] -> R/C -> LAB -> KeyError
```